# Site-To-Site VPN does not work for one specific subnet

Tags: cisco-asa, site-to-site-vpn

We are using Cisco 5500 series ASA for sites HQ and BX and there is a site-to-site vpn in between,

BX (subnet 192.168.6.0) can access to subnet 192.168.200.0 subnet at HQ but can't access 192.168.0.0 subnet at HQ.

Packet trace shows us that the data is being transmitted to both sites but it drops. I can't locate the source of the problem. I sense it is regarding routing but can't point the problem.

I know that it is better for me to post the logs but I don't know how. I need a hand on this, noobe here.

Thanks and happy new year.
K.

Comment: When you say `192.168.0.0 subnet`, do you mean `192.168.0.0/24` subnet? And what do you mean by "to both sites"?

Comment: Is the endpoint of the VPN at HQ on the 192.168.200.0 subnet? If so, has the 192.168.0.0 subnet been configured with a route back to the 192.168.6.0 subnet?

Is there a conflict with another subnet, possibly at the end of another site-to-site VPN? Consider the networks of any business partners.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. HQ has a couple of subnets: 200.x, 0.x, and 1.x. Where can I identify if it is routed back to BX site (6.x) subnet?

Comment: David, Yes that's what I meant. To both sites means that from Point A to B and Point B to A I am getting all the green checks with package track.

Comment: We called Cisco, and they confirmed that this was a bug of the ASA we use. The data was not being encrypted so ASA was not sending it back. Guess what? Tech told us to restart the firewall, and problem went away. It sounds stupid, but sometimes you have to remember: Router is a f***ing router and it requires f***ing restart. Excuse my language but I really got frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in the firewall. Cisco confirmed it. Router restart fixed the problem.

Comment: We're seeing similar issues -- did they give you a bug ref at all? what code version is your ASA on?